# `projectNotLinked` Error, Even if I can see its linked on google play console, DEC 2017, API V2

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, google-client

`projectNotLinked` Error, Even if I can see its linked on google play console!

**Details:**

Google Play Developer API V2.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{package}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionsID}/tokens/{tokens}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

I have testd on both Google apis-explore and auth playground:
`https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidpublisher/v2/androidpublisher.purchases.subscriptions.get?...`
Have finalcial report permission.
[image]

[image]

I have searched through stackoverflow, but answers before 2/3 years ago simply do not work.

How can I solve this problem? What is the problem, any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) give this URL `GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token`. and you use also **?key={YOUR_API_KEY}** . check this .

Comment: Sorry, but It does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that problem.

I was trying to test those on Google APIs-explore and auth playground.
But that sad news those does not work.(tested in 2017 DEC, JAN 2018)
But google client API (java) works fine. :) That means we cant test those via  Google APIs-explore and auth playground.

And one other Google in-app billing service tests take real credit card and do real charge on the account.

WE WOULD BE HAPPY if google's in-app billing service team update their docs.
And make all APIs working in Google APIs-explore and auth playground, or remove them or keep a notice that those have been archived.

And last one: A way to test google play in-app billing via a fake/sample credit card. :)

[UPDATE: Developer's account is charged as a test card (SEP' 2018)]

Thanks

Comment: So, did you try this for subscriptions?  I get the same results... Sometimes I get account linked, sometimes I do not.  However, I am running this in the internal test mode, using a test credit card... Is that why?

Comment: Yes for the subscription.
Try to refresh token.

Comment: Turns out, in a way, yes, I needed to refresh everything... I had firsted test a purchase in real life, paying real money, $1.99.  Then, I added test license account users, and was purchasing/cancelling the same object, so somehow google was confused and giving me inconsistent answers.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add another subscription product in my Google Play Console. Seems to be some kind of inconsistency problem in Google services.